# Volley JsonArray on Android do not work less than 5 correct

Tags: android, listview, android-volley

I use the Volley Library in my app.
I use a method to transfer myself from Activity A to Activity B by intent.

```
     StringURL             StringURL
 --------------   intent  --------------
 | Activity A |  >---->>  | Activity B |     
 --------------           --------------
mystring url ====> http://www.articler.ir/android_php/search.php?Method=rate&CAT=مهندسی%20عمران
```

Then in Activity B, I use the server to receive content from the server, but apparently, this content is received on Android less than 5 empty.
Please guide me exactly where it can be. I once again put this question in this link [List View does not show anything bellow lollipop version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49364368/list-view-does-not-show-anything-bellow-lollipop-version) and find root problem, But I do not understand why the Response from the server in Android 4.4 is empty. But the same Response is true on Android 5+. How to fix the problem? Please HELP me, thank you Again.

[Android 5-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmyBV.jpg)

[Android 5+](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvZJA.jpg)

in Activity B :

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {
    private List<Model> myList = new ArrayList<Model>();
    private  ArrayList<String> authors;
    private  ArrayList<String> keywords;
    String FirstURL ;
    String SearchURL;
//my stirng url ===> 
// http://www.articler.ir/android_php/search.php?Method=rate&CAT=مهندسی%20عمران 
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
        final SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout = rootView.findViewById(R.id.fm_one);
        final CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(),  myList);
        final ListView listView1 = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.myList1);

        Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
        FirstURL = intent.getStringExtra("SearchURL");
        SearchURL = FirstURL.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
        Log.d("Search", "Search: " + SearchURL);

        myList.removeAll(myList);

        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);


        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(SearchURL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                Log.d("VolleyRes", "response: " + response);

                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {

                        JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);

                        Model model = new Model();
                        model.setTitle(jsonObject.getString("title"));
                        model.setMainText(jsonObject.getString("mainText"));
                        model.setrate(jsonObject.getDouble("rate"));
                        model.setYear(jsonObject.getInt("year"));
                        model.setConfName(jsonObject.getString("confName"));
                        model.setProductId(jsonObject.getInt("productId"));
                        model.setCountView(jsonObject.getInt("countView"));
                        model.setPdfURL(jsonObject.getString("pdfURL"));
                        // authors is json array
                        authors = new ArrayList<String>();
                        JSONArray authorArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("authors");
                        for (int j = 0; j < authorArray.length(); j++) {
                            if (!authors.contains(authorArray.getString(j)) && !authorArray.isNull(j)) {
                                authors.add((String) authorArray.get(j));
                            }
                        }
                        model.setAuthor(authors);

                        // Keywords is json array
                        keywords = new ArrayList<String>();
                        JSONArray keywordArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Keywords");
                        for (int k = 0; k < keywordArray.length(); k++) {
                            if (!keywords.contains(keywordArray.getString(k)) && !keywordArray.isNull(k)) {
                                keywords.add((String) keywordArray.get(k));
                            }
                        }
                        model.setKeywords(keywords);
                        myList.add(model);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                VolleyLog.d("VolleyErr", "ErrorMassage: " + error.getMessage());
            }

        });

        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayRequest);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);






        listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {



            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                int year = myList.get(position).getYear();
                int productId = myList.get(position).getProductId();
                int countView = myList.get(position).getCountView();
                double rate = myList.get(position).getrate();
                String title = myList.get(position).getTitle();
                String mainText = myList.get(position).getMainText();
                String confName = myList.get(position).getConfName();
                ArrayList authors = myList.get(position).getAuthor();
                ArrayList keywords = myList.get(position).getKeywords();
                String pdfURL = myList.get(position).getPdfURL();


                SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.
                        getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.putInt("productId", productId); //InputString: from the EditText
                editor.putInt("countView", countView);
                editor.putFloat("rate", (float) rate);
                editor.putString("pdfURL",pdfURL);
                editor.putString("title",title);
                editor.putString("mainText",mainText);
                editor.putString("confName",confName);
                editor.putString("authors", String.valueOf(authors));
                editor.putString("keywords", String.valueOf(keywords));
                editor.putInt("year", year);
                editor.commit();


                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),DetailActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        // finish();
                    }
                }, 1500);

            }
        });

        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
         new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener(){

             @Override
             public void onRefresh() {
                 ((MyTabActivity)getActivity()).refreshNow();
                 Toast.makeText(getContext(), "بروزرسانی صفحه!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
         });


        return rootView;
    }


}
```

My AppController:

```
public class AppController extends Application {

    public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    private static AppController mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized that URL with Persian fonts on Android less than 5 is not supported. So I need to change the string by encoding it so I used the method below to change it.

```
//this is initial string url ====> http://www.articler.ir/android_php/search.php?Method=rate&CAT=مهندسی%20عمران

String MyKey = مهندسی عمران;

final String EncodeKey= URLEncoder.encode(MyKey , "UTF-8");

String EncodeURL = " http://www.articler.ir/android_php/search.php?Method=rate&CAT= " + EncodeKey;
```

after changing this part, my response is correct, like 5+ version;